# Pinterest button - Parameter 'source_url' -is not a valid URL format

Tags: pin-it-sdk

I am using Pinterest button in my website for sharing the image.
I have used third part widget from addThis.com for attaining this functionality.
The code in my html looks like below..

```
<div class="social-media-icons1">
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share" title="Pinterest"  >
<img class="social-media1" th:src="@{/img/common/btn/btn_pinterest.gif}" />
</a>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5368b8795f957cb6"></script>
</div>
```

but when i share the image i get the below error
Parameter 'source_url' 
`(value https://10.52.165.234/frenchplace/b43130519/12081907?category=BONOBO)`
 is not a valid URL format.

Can someone help me what is the solution for this problem.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to know what the issue is.
Actually i was using Self-Signed HTTPS.But for pinIt to work we need a authenticated SSL certificate.
I tested using HTTP it works.:)

Answer (score 0):

Those widgets often use the HREF attribute as your image source. Consider this:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/images/my-image.png" class="addthis_button_pinterest_share" title="Pinterest">
    <img class="social-media1" th:src="@{/img/common/btn/btn_pinterest.gif}" />
</a>
```